# How to get features from cluster source for current extent?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

How to get features from cluster source for current extent? I need to collect all features from cluster for current extent and zoom state.

I tried this:

```
  this.mapService.map.getView().on('change:resolution', (evt) => {
   const a =  (this.clusterVector.getSource() as VectorSource).getFeaturesByExtent(this.clusterVector.getSource().getExtent());
   console.log(a);
  });
```

It does not work for me correctly, it returns more features when user zoom in instead less.

I have made some research and now there is:

```
    this.mapService.map.getView().on('change:resolution', (evt) => {
            const extent = this.mapService.map
              .getView()
              .calculateExtent(this.mapService.map.getSize());
            const features = 

this.clusterSource.getFeaturesInExtent(extent);
```

Is it proper way?

Comment: You mean features from the current view extent? 
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#calculateExtent

If you pass the extent of the source you will get the all features of the source.

Comment: Yes, I need to get from current extent. I tried also this (check out the question)

Comment: So you still get all of them? I would suggest to listen to map moveend event instead of resolution change